# React Redux Store updating, but component not re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, redux, render, react-redux

Using the terminal to test my dispatched actions, Redux-logger shows that my state is being correctly updated. However, my component is not re-rendering as a result of the state change. I've looked at the SO answers regarding component not re-rendering, a majority of the responses claim that the state is being mutated; as a result, Redux won't re-render. However, I'm using Lodash's merge to deep-dup an object, I'm pretty sure I'm not returning a modified object. (Please see attached snippet below)

Would love to hear some advice from you guys, pulling my hair out on this one!

```js
const usersReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  Object.freeze(state); // avoid mutating state

  console.log(state); 
  // returns an empty object  
  let newState = merge({}, state);
  console.log(newState); 
  // returns my state with my dispatched action object inside  already???
  // newState for some reason already has new dispatched action
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_USER:
      let newUser = {[action.user.id] = action.user};
      return merge(newUser, newUser);
    case RECEIVE_USERS:
      newState = {};
      action.users.forEach(user => {
        newState[user.id] = user;
      });
      return merge({}, newState);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

React Container Component

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { receiveUsers, receiveUser, refreshAll, requestUsers, requestUser } from '../../actions/user_actions';
import allUsers from '../../reducers/selectors';
import UserList from './user_list';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  users: allUsers(state), // allUsers (selector that takes the state specfically the user Object and returns an array of user Objects)
  state
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  requestUser: () => dispatch(requestUser()),
  requestUsers: () => dispatch(requestUsers()),
  receiveUsers: (users) => dispatch(receiveUsers(users)),
  receiveUser: (user) => dispatch(receiveUser(user)),
  refreshAll: (users) => dispatch(refreshAll(users))
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(UserList);
```

React Presentational component

```js
import React from 'react';

class UserList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { users, state } = this.props;

    const userItems = users.map((user, idx) => {
        return(<li key={idx}>{user.username}</li>);
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          { userItems }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UserList;
```

React Store

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import RootReducer from '../reducers/root_reducer';

const logger = createLogger();
const configureStore = (preloadedState = {}) => {
  return createStore(
    RootReducer, 
    preloadedState,
    applyMiddleware(logger));
};

// const configureStore = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(logger));

// oddly enough, when I have the store as a constant and not a function that returns the store constant, dispatching actions through the terminal will correctly update the state and rerender the component 

export default configureStore;
```

React Selector

```js
const allUsers = ({ users }) => {
  return Object.keys(users).map(id => (
    users[id]
  ));
};

export default allUsers;
```

Comment: Can you add your component code? It could be a problem with the way you wire your component to the store.

Comment: It may not be related to your problem, but none of your usages of merge make any sense to me.  What exactly are you expecting to accomplish?  I recommend you just use splats, e.g. `return {...state, x: 42}`

Comment: Where do you add `usersReducer` to the store? Can you verify that your components `mapStateToProps` is getting called when the store state changes? If not it could mean that your reducer is not being executed properly.

Comment: @Mustafa In my RootReducer I call CombineReducers({ users: usersReducer });

I think you're onto something, it doesn't seem like mapStateToProps is being called but isn't that automatically invoked when you dispatch an action?

Comment: @Tonyhliu it should be called when your store state changes. This means that it's not a problem with the render, but likely with the way the component is being connected to the store.

Comment: @Mustafa - Interesting enough, when I create my store as a constant (the way I have it currently is that it's a FUNCTION that returns the store), everything works the way I expect it to. Any ideas as to why that may be? (Refer to React Store snippet above)

Comment: @Tonyhliu Maybe because you are not calling configureStore anywhere in your app.. I haven't seen the store getting created like this, so not sure if it's even possible. Also this `return merge(newUser, newUser);` doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Mustafa I meant to do newState, newUser. I call configureStore in my entry file. I've seen it done on some resource that I found but can't figure out why they do it and how it works... Thanks for your help

Comment: So, did you fix it? If not can you link to your github repo?

Comment: Sort of. I left my store as a constant instead of a function that returns the store. Check it out here : https://github.com/Tonyhliu/githubWidget.

Comment: I'm also new to React Redux, would love to hear some good resources to utilize to learn about middleware and how to handle ajax requests.

Comment: Doesn't make sense, `left my store as a constant instead of a function`, `const usersReducer` is a function.

Comment: For tutorials, checkout these https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuNEz8XtB51K-x3bwCC9uNM_cxXaiCcRY, https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLcfAVClOb1Bh9TrHOAfAiB60ohBszIn3h If you're ready to pay a little, checkout this course https://www.udemy.com/react-redux-tutorial/ by *Stephen Grider*. One of the best instructors ever.

Comment: And for middleware, ajax requests, you can checkout these videos by Stephen Grider https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQCaS3atWyNHEy5PkDXdpNg/videos

Comment: Refer to store snippet. When configureStore is a constant that refers to the store object, everything works as assumed. WHen configureStore is a function that returns the store object, things dont' work as expected.

Comment: That's because when you pass `configureStore` as a function, calling `configureStore` will return another function *and we have to call it again to get the desired response*, when you don't pass it as a function, calling `configureStore` will return the store. Anyways to achieve what you wanted you can do `const preloadedState = {};
const configureStore = createStore(
 { ...rootReducer, ...preloadedState },
 applyMiddleware(logger)
);`

Answer (score 23):

I had a similar problem, just in case someone stumbles upon this, I needed to clone the array in order to *re-render* the view:

```
export const addFieldRow = () => (
    (dispatch: any, getState: any) => {
        const state = getState();
        const myArrayOfObjects = myArrayOfObjectsProp(state);
        const newObject = {
            key: "",
            value: "",
        };
        myArrayOfObjects.push(newObject);
        dispatch(addFieldRowAction({ myArrayOfObjects: [...myArrayOfObjects] })); <== here
    }
);
```

Comment: You saved me a HEADACHE :-)
for those who want to how make a shallow copy: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-clone-an-array-in-javascript-1d3183468f6a/

Comment: You save me a day

Answer (score 5):

Common problem in this case is using not reactive operations for changing state. For example use concat() for array, but not push() and so on.

Comment: Thank you! This was a major pain for me! Using push does not update the state. Either use the spread operator `const x = [...x, y]` or use concat....

Answer (score 4):

I use this solution to do it.
I put the users on my state and update it on any change, with componentWillReceiveProps. Hope it helps :-)

```
class UserList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       console.log(this.props);
       this.state = {
          users: props.users
       };
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (this.props.users !== nextProps.users) {
            this.setState({
                users: nextProps.users,
            });
        }
    }

  render() {
    const { users } = this.state;

    const userItems = users.map((user, idx) => {
        return(<li key={idx}>{user.username}</li>);
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          { userItems }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UserList;
```

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` is an unsafe method in class-based/container components as at React v16

Comment: This question is about Redux, your solution doesn't include it in any way.

Answer (score 2):

What do your React components look like? Are you using internal state in them or props to push the data down. Usually I see the issue is with people setting the internal state of props with Redux state. You should be pushing props down to the components and they will re-render on update.

Also, check out
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en

to see if the props are really changing.

Answer (score 2):

Create new copy of array from the prop state to re-render the component

```
render() {

const {allPost} = this.props;
//Use the spread operator to create a new copy of the array
const posts = [...allPost];

 const plansList = () => {
     return posts.length < 1 ? null : posts && <PlansList allPost={posts} 
   />;
 };

return (
  <>
    <Container className="mt-lg-5 pt-lg-5">
    {plansList()}
  </Container>
  </>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i spent lot of time to find out that when using more than 1 reducer (with *combineReducers*), then your *mapStateToProps* should point the correct reducer names, for example

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  someVar: state.yourReducerName.someVar,
  loading: state.yourReducerName.loading,
  error: state.yourReducerName.error
});
```